# Can't seem to pass information between function and main

Tags: c, parameters

I can't get my code to run properly. Here it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void intro_msg( ); 
float compass_value( );
float direction(  );

int  main ( void )
{

  float compass;

  intro_msg( ) ;

  compass_value(compass );

  direction(compass );

  return ( 0 ) ;

}  

void intro_msg(void)
{
   printf("Welcome to the Compass Program \n \n");
}

float compass_value(compass )
{
   printf("Please enter a value for the compass direction. (0 - 360 degress ) :  ");
   scanf("%f", &compass);
   printf("You entered %f degrees \n" , compass);
   return(compass);
}


float direction(compass)
{
   if (compass >= 354.38 && compass <= 360.00){
      printf("You are heading North \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 0.0 && compass <= 39.37){
      printf("You are heading North \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 39.38 && compass <= 84.37){
      printf("You are heading Northeast \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 84.38 && compass <= 129.37){
      printf("You are heading East \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 129.38 && compass <= 174.37){
      printf("You are heading Southeast \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 174.38 && compass <= 219.37){
      printf("You are heading South \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 219.38 && compass <= 264.37){
      printf("You are heading Southwest \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 264.38 && compass <= 309.37){
      printf("You are heading West \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 309.38 && compass <= 354.37){
      printf("You are heading Northwest \n");
  }
   else 
   {
      printf("You did not enter a value between 0 - 360 degrees");
   }
}
```

I'm trying to obtain a degree between 0 - 360 from the user, record it and then determine the direction they are facing (North, South, Northeast, etc.) but my value for compass is never being recording.

Immediately after asking the user for the value, I go to print the value and I get 0.0, not what the user entered. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I have a " { "  place under my int main( void ) in my actual code, I mistakenly removed it before placing this question. So that is not the issue.

Comment: If you made an error in the code you posted that isn't the issue, [edit] your question and fix it instead of saying so in the comments. Tag info (like the language you're using) belongs in tags and not the title.

Answer (score 0):

In the declaration

```
float direction(compass)
```

what type do you think `compass` is?  (Hint:  it is not a `float` or `double`.)

---

Here is how I would write this program (tested):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ARRAY_SIZE(A)   (sizeof A / sizeof A[0])
void intro_msg (void)
{
    printf ("Welcome to the Compass Program\n\n");
}

float compass_value (void)
{
    double  direction;
    int bad = 1;
    do {
        printf ("Please enter a value for the compass direction (0 to 360 degrees):  ");
        fflush (stdout);
        if (1 == scanf ("%lf", &direction))
            bad = 0;
    } while (bad);
    printf ("You entered %f degrees\n", direction);
    return direction;
}

static const struct {
    float   lo, hi;
    const char *name;
} dirs [] = {
    {354.38, 360.0,  "North"},
    {  0.0,   39.37, "North"},
    { 39.37,  84.37, "Northeast"},
    { 84.37, 129.37, "East"},
    {129.37, 174.37, "Southeast"},
    {174.37, 219.37, "South"},
    {219.37, 264.37, "Southwest"},
    {264.37, 309.37, "West"},
    {309.37, 354.37, "Northwest"},
};

void direction (double compass)
{
    int j;
    for (j = 0;  j < ARRAY_SIZE (dirs);  ++j)
        if (compass >= dirs [j] .lo  &&  compass <= dirs [j] .hi)
        {
            printf ("Direction is %s\n", dirs [j] .name);
            return;
        }
    printf ("Direction is not between 0 and 360 degrees.\n");
}

int main (void)
{
    double  compass;

    intro_msg ();
    compass = compass_value ();
    direction (compass);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is it default type?

Should it be
    float direction(float compass)

Comment: @JesseT:  Indeed it is.  What is the default type?

Comment: The default type is int

Comment: @JesseT:  Yes it is.  So if 36.75 is passed as an `int`, what do you think happens with `scanf("%f", &compass)`?

Comment: The ".75" gets dropped. I now declared it as a float, so this shouldn't happen now.

Comment: @JesseT:  That is a step in the right direction.  Also, it makes no sense for `compass_value()` to have a parameter passed.  It can declare its own private `compass` and return that.

Answer (score 0):

This should fix your problems

```
#include <stdio.h>

void intro_msg( ); 
float compass_value(float);      // You had not specified Argument type
float direction(float);          // You had not specified Argument type

int  main ( void )
{

  float compass;

  intro_msg( ) ;

  compass_value(compass);

  direction(compass);

  return ( 0 ) ;

}  

void intro_msg(void)
{
   printf("Welcome to the Compass Program \n \n");
}

float compass_value(float compass)    // You did not specify type
{
   printf("Please enter a value for the compass direction. (0 - 360 degress ) :  ");
   scanf("%f", &compass);
   printf("You entered %f degrees \n" , compass);
   return(compass);
}


float direction(float &compass)          // You did not specify type, also made it a reference
{
   if (compass >= 354.38 && compass <= 360.00){
      printf("You are heading North \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 0.0 && compass <= 39.37){
      printf("You are heading North \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 39.38 && compass <= 84.37){
      printf("You are heading Northeast \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 84.38 && compass <= 129.37){
      printf("You are heading East \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 129.38 && compass <= 174.37){
      printf("You are heading Southeast \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 174.38 && compass <= 219.37){
      printf("You are heading South \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 219.38 && compass <= 264.37){
      printf("You are heading Southwest \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 264.38 && compass <= 309.37){
      printf("You are heading West \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 309.38 && compass <= 354.37){
      printf("You are heading Northwest \n");
  }
   else 
   {
      printf("You did not enter a value between 0 - 360 degrees");
   }
}
```

Now, the problems with your code were that you did not specify the argument type in the function declaration and definitions. You were also passing compass by value, due to which the value you were accepting from the user in `compass_value` was not being put into your `compass` in the main. So, It always showed north. To fix this, pass `compass` by reference as indicated.

If you don't want to pass by reference, this code will help you

```
#include <stdio.h>

void intro_msg( ); 
float compass_value(float );          // You had not specified Argument type
float direction(float  );             // You had not specified Argument type 

int  main ( void )
{

  float compass;

  intro_msg( ) ;

  compass=compass_value(compass );   // Since the function was returning a compass, assign that value to the compass in main()

  direction(compass );

  return ( 0 ) ;

}  

void intro_msg(void)
{
   printf("Welcome to the Compass Program \n \n");
}

float compass_value(float compass )        // You did not specify type
{
   printf("Please enter a value for the compass direction. (0 - 360 degress ) :  ");
   scanf("%f", &compass);
   printf("You entered %f degrees \n" , compass);
   return(compass);
}


float direction(float compass)              // You did not specify type
{
   if (compass >= 354.38 && compass <= 360.00){
      printf("You are heading North \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 0.0 && compass <= 39.37){
      printf("You are heading North \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 39.38 && compass <= 84.37){
      printf("You are heading Northeast \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 84.38 && compass <= 129.37){
      printf("You are heading East \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 129.38 && compass <= 174.37){
      printf("You are heading Southeast \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 174.38 && compass <= 219.37){
      printf("You are heading South \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 219.38 && compass <= 264.37){
      printf("You are heading Southwest \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 264.38 && compass <= 309.37){
      printf("You are heading West \n");
  }
   else if (compass >= 309.38 && compass <= 354.37){
      printf("You are heading Northwest \n");
  }
   else 
   {
      printf("You did not enter a value between 0 - 360 degrees");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you know that you are actually passing compass variable into compass_value() by value. Means that the change wont be reflected into the compass variable of the main function.

I see that you are returning the read value, but you dont recieve it into anything at the call to compass_value()  in your main function. Try recieving it :

```
compass = compass_value(compass);
```